# how to save rest web service data in android?

Tags: android, rest

I am working on application, my requirements is when i post data as parameters like ID, Value etc using rest webservice and than i get some data as a response like deviceID, VendorID, driverID.

MY application senerio is. when user first time install app he/she can see the screen that enter the above data like ID, Value etc and some response appears that response is basically user configuration like deviceID, VendorID, driverID and has to save. And and than automatically move to the next screen using intent.

Now when user close app and than again open he/she will automatically move to list screen if he/she is login other wise stay on login. NO configuration screen at the, because its setting first time save in app (deviceID, VendorID, driverID).

How to save that configuration data of user first, which one is the best way.

Please give me best solution like in tutorial form and also little bit explenation.

Thanks

Comment: use SharedPreferences for store these kind of data. see this link -http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends a lot on what the "some response" is and how much data do you want to store.
In Android Storage Options:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

There's Shared Preferences:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html
[How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

Maintaining a database seems to be an optimal way.
You can store, update or over-write the data according to your need. The Id's can be maintained in tables, and further info with each Id can be associated in rows, increasing attributes and relating it with keys.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html
http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/